# mailchimp webhooks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp

I am using `Ruby on rails 3` and `hominid` gem wrapper to `MailChimp API

I need to use webhooks. However, when i try add a new webhook throw this error message on mailchimp screen.

The URL is: `http://www.my-example-site.com.ar/mail-chimp-callback`

This is a valid URL. When a use curl post well.

Excuse me but which could be my error?

Which could be my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was a code 500. SO i reinspect my code. The problem was  a `render :nothing => true`